# How to remove the parent from current url path while redirecting using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have been struggling with .htaccess modifications over my site throughout. Here is what i need

I am redirecting user to login page with following url rewritting rule in
.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^welcome/ index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^log-in/$ log-in.php [L]
```

The login page when called, the url path that appears in the browser looks like this

```
http://localhost:90/vrp/log-in/
```

On login page i have a link added for forget password

```
<a class="color-aqua" href="forget-password/">click here</a> to reset your password.</p>
```

Rule for rewritting it is

```
#Forget Password Rule#
RewriteRule ^forget-password/$ forget-password.php [NC,L]
```

The Forget password page when called, the url path that appears in the browser looks like this

```
http://localhost:90/vrp/log-in/forget-password/
```

I do not want that `/log-in` to be their on url path. It should be

```
http://localhost:90/vrp/forget-password/
```

I did a lot more search and edit stuff around but at the end could not find any way to do it. Is the required thing is possible because this is kind of appending format which may further maximize the url path when user moves in to the portal which may confuse in future.

Comment: There is some information missing in the description. The rewrite rules you posted will _not_ by themselves modify your URLs shown in the browser. There has to be some other component involved.

Comment: what components you are talking about???

Comment: I cannot tell you. Maybe additional rewrite rules stored somewhere else. I can only point out what I observe, not what might be the situation on your system. Only you can tell that.

Comment: Well i have edited the question a little. Could you check it